# imap_search() unknown search criterion "OR"

Tags: php, search, imap, rfc

Trying to build a IMAP Search query to filter out specific mails via php code... Pushed into a situation where I must use the "OR" search criteria.

```
<?php
$search_string = 'OR (SUBJECT "FedEx" SUBJECT "USPS")';
$search_string = 'OR SUBJECT "FedEx" SUBJECT "USPS"';
$search_string = 'SUBJECT "FedEx" OR SUBJECT "USPS"';
$search_string = 'OR (SUBJECT "FedEx") OR (SUBJECT "USPS")';
$search_string = 'OR (SUBJECT "FedEx") (SUBJECT "USPS")';
//all of the search strings when used separately didn't work

$emails = imap_search($inbox, $search_string);
?>
```

But when used, php throws the error `PHP Notice:  Unknown: Unknown search criterion: OR (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0`

When referred [php docs for IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) it says the documentation might be inaccurate and directed to [RFC 2060](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2060.html) so When referring section 6.4.4 for search command, it mentions that we can use OR, NOT and few extra search criteria...

so used it in prefix position, infix position and tried using parenthesis as suggested in RFC 2060 but all in vain

Also Came across the [php bug entry](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45140) but not sure if this is a bug or it needs to be used in some other way!

Anybody with solutions / workarounds?

I would hate to iterate over every mail and check in code if it satisfies the condition... I'd like that to be accomplished via IMAP search

---

**Edit/Updates:**

imap_search function is not fully compatible with IMAP4. the c-client used as of now supports only IMAP2 and some search criterion will not be available for use such as "OR"

**So a php code similar to:**

```
$inbox   = imap_open('{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'foo@example.com', 'pass123', OP_READONLY);
$search_string = 'SUBJECT "FedEx" OR SUBJECT "USPS"';   
$emails = imap_search($inbox, $search_string);
```

will throw an error saying "Unknown search criterion"

**observations and reference:**
git repo : https://github.com/php/php-src

**PHP source trace:**( ref: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/imap/php_imap.c )
/ext/imap/php_imap.c -> line no : 4126
imap_search => line no : 4148

**c-client library source trace:**
src/c-client/mail.c -> line no : 3973

/docs/internal.txt -> line no : 1919 => mail_criteria()
criteria IMAP2-format search criteria string
WARNING: This function does not accept IMAP4 search criteria.

**IMAP2 RFC1064** => [ ref: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1064 ] [page: 13]
**IMAP4 RFC2060** => [ ref: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2060.html ] [section: 6.4.4]

Note:
The core search functionality in a core module(IMAP) is still not available in PHP. Hope this will be brought to the developer community's attention...

But I'm not sure about which PHP version uses the IMAP4 compatible c-client...

1. Is there a way to force php to just update/use the latest c-client
   library?
2. Or the current latest(as of 11Apr 2016) c-client supports only IMAP2?
3. Should we modify the library source code and compile and
   install?
4. ***Or Is there any other PHP libraries developed by 3rd parties that we
   can use to accomplish the same(imap protocol mail search, retrieve
   for those mail providers who doesn't support OAuth2)?***

Comment: Have you checked that your server doesn't have a bug? Many "offbrand" servers have minimal or broken search implementations.

Comment: Looks like a php bug, looking at the link. It says something about using a new cclient?

Comment: @Max , The IMAP server is gmail server... It's highly unlikely that the imap server is faulty

Comment: @Max , Do you know of any new c-client library that's compatible with php 5.4 ? if so please do share the link...

Answer (score 2):

I solved this doing several imap_search sentences to simulate "OR".

```
$criteria = 'UNSEEN FROM "someaddr@gmail.com"|UNSEEN FROM "@onedomain.com"|UNSEEN FROM "@anotherdomain.org"'
$criterias = explode('|', $criteria);
$emails = array();
foreach ($criterias as $search) {
    $emails_ = imap_search($inbox, $search);
    if ($emails_)
        $emails = array_merge($emails, $emails_);
}
$emails = array_unique($emails);
```

Comment: Finally, I too handled it on the code rather than using the search string... My objective was to filter them based on their subject and contents so used a little bit of php string comparison and unix's grep to rummage through the mail content(after saving it as a file). also read the comments i posted for the other answer... about using `array_intersect()` and `array_unique()`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this.?

```
$inbox   = imap_open('{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'foo@example.com', 'pass123', OP_READONLY);

$search_string = 'SINCE "08-Mar-2011" OR SUBJECT "FedEx" OR SUBJECT "USPS"';

$emails = imap_search($inbox, $search_string);
```

Comment: did you check if the "OR" search criterion work at all? if so please share me the `phpinfo()`... I have my suspicion on "c-client" library (i have 2007f version) may be you'd have a different one...

Comment: The father of IMAP "Mark Crespin" died on 2012 and since then php didn't update the IMAP c-client library and was using the old IMAP-2007f version that supports only IMAP2 version we can't expect any magical updates to happen soon for PHP IMAP. It seems the only way is to search multiple times with imap (proportional to how much OR conditions we have in our query. in my case, it is more than 10 FEDEX,UPS,USPS,DHL, ... and other conditions) and `array_unique()` / `array_intersect()` the message ids... but 10 times `imap_search()` is gonna kill my server if my IMAP user base keeps on increasing